# Star * symbol found on second line of Fortran function declaration

Tags: fortran

When examining some legacy Fortran code, I've found a subroutine declaration that is the following:

```
       SUBROUTINE CLIP2G (fcut,TIME,NUMS,NUMG,CLIPG,CLIPGL,CLIPGR,
     * MODE,PHZ)
```

What does the `*` signify in this context?  Does the star `*` mean that the subroutine declaration spans two lines rather than one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a line continuation mark in fixed form Fortran. It marks that this line is a continuation of the previous one.  It may be any Fortran recognized character that is not a blank (space  ) or zero (`0`), but it must be placed in column 6.  If character position 6 contains a blank or zero, the line is the initial line of a new statement, which begins in character position 7. (F2018 6.3.3.3)

A more thorough discussion of line continuations in fixed and free Fortran form, including the "intersection form" that can be included in files of either form, is at [Fortran Wiki:
Continuation lines](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines).

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir F! Also, +1 for mentioning that the character must be placed in column 6. Great and concise explanation.